# How to Temporarily Make a Google Drive File Public Using Google Drive API?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm working on a project where I need to make a Google Drive file temporarily public for download and then make it private again. I'm using the Google Drive API in PHP.

Here's the code I'm currently using to get the download link of the file:

```php
/**
 * Gets the download link from Drive (without going through our server).
 * @param string $fileId id of the file to be searched.
 * @return string Direct download link of the file.
 */
public function getWebContentLink(string $fileId): string {
    self::setPermissionPublic($fileId);

    $file = $this->service->files->get(
        $fileId, [
            'fields' => 'webContentLink'
        ]
    );

    return $file->getWebContentLink();
}

/**
 * Sets a file's permissions to public.
 * @param string $fileId id of the file to be made public.
 * @return void
 */
private function setPermissionPublic(string $fileId): void {
    $permission = new \Google\Service\Drive\Permission([
        'role' => 'reader',
        'type' => 'anyone'
    ]);
    $permission = $this->service->permissions->create($fileId, $permission);
}
```

However, this makes the file permanently public. I would like to make it public only for a short period of time (e.g., 1 minute) and then make it private again.

I've looked into the [Google Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) and I'm aware that there isn't a built-in method for temporary links. I've also tried using the `expireDate` field in the permissions resource, but it didn't work as expected.

Moreover, I'm expecting a high volume of requests (over 1000), so I need a solution that won't overload the server. I also know that Google Drive isn't the best choice for that, but can I get anything that helps my needs?

***Any*** help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Realistically you'd probably need to keep a log on your own site of the file IDs you've made public, and and the time you want the link to expire, and then have a cron job which runs every minute or so, looks at the list and finds any whose time has expired (and aren't marked as having already been processed by the job), and then connects to the google API to change the permissions back to private again.

Comment: I could handle that with triggers i guess. Keeping the expiration time of each file in a database.

Comment: A SQL trigger occurs immediately in response to something in the database, e.g. a row being written or something like that. It can't then run on a schedule to make sure things are updated on time. I doubt this would work with triggers. A cron job would make a lot more sense. But yeah you would need to keep the expiration time of each file in a database, and probably a record of whether the last action you took was to make it public or private, so that the job knows whether it needs to act on each specific expired item, or whether it's already been acted on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private function setPermissionPublic(string $fileId): void {
    $permission = new \Google\Service\Drive\Permission([
        'role' => 'reader',
        'type' => 'anyone'
    ]);
    $permission = $this->service->permissions->create($fileId, $permission);
}
```

The code above sets a file to public there is no way to limit how long it is public.  If you want to make the code private again after a minute.  I suggest that you simply run a [permissins.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/delete) after a minute to have the file reverted to private.

Comment: Just a bit curious, but would this help? https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_sleep.asp

Comment: @CenturyTuna not unless you want the webserver to be unavailable for large chunks of time, no.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that woudn't be the best with concurrent access... @ADyson is right